# Angular http post method gives typescript error

Tags: angular, typescript, typeerror, angular-http

I am using Angular 5. An i interact with an API through a service. I have a method that i want to use for posting into the API. The problem is, if i specify the type of the post method to "Candidate"  object i get the following warning:

```
src/app/candidates.service.ts(17,12): error TS2558: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.
```

My function's code is the following:

```
  addCandidate(candidate: Candidate): Observable<Candidate> {
return this.http.post<Candidate>(this.apiUrl, candidate, httpOptions);}
```

I think i am not using types here correctly, but i am not sure.

Comment: Where does httpOptions come from ? The httpClient methods signature depends on multiple things

Comment: The http options looks like this:     const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}) };   I basically need to upload some objects to the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you are using the old, deprecated `Http` class instead of `HttpClient`.

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http'; //old, deprecated client. Does not support generic types
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'; //new client
```

Replace `private http: Http` by `private http: HttpClient` in your service's constructor, and import HttpClient like this

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http`
```

Dont forget to import HttpClientModule in your AppModule module

```
//app.module.ts
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

....
imports: [HttpClientModule]
```

Comment: Thank you  very much. It seems indeed i had to change the http client in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Does the http post method return a candidate? If not just change to `Observable` instead of `Observable<Candidate>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed from Observable<Candidate> to Observable. However the error persists. 
It seems to be caused by the <Candidate> type specified after post method, right before the post function parameters. 
If i eliminate it from there, another error occurs (Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.)

Comment: Try `Observable<any>`. It is similar to just having `Observable`, except it shouldn't throw any errors. But actually, if you are expecting the POST request to return data, you should set the type of that generic to be the type of the POST response data.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend removing the `<Candidate>` because in the post method all it cares for is that you sent it json data. You have also already typed it in your `addCandidate(candidate: Candidate)` method param declaration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about the same thing, but i wanted to keep consistency.